# Terminal says terminal isn't installed

Tags: command-line

When I type "terminal" in the terminal, it returns "the program 'terminal' is currently not installed". Why is that?

Comment: What exactly would you like to do in the terminal? Do you want to open another terminal within the terminal?

Comment: Hmm... why do you type "terminal" in the terminal? what's the sense?

Comment: @user300458 Curiosity.

Comment: Well, only curiosity induces such question. Lol.

Comment: @abti well, that's an important thing :)

Comment: @user300458 I agree with you. It is an important thing in some way.

Comment: Furthermore it says in terminal: You can install it by typing:
`sudo apt-get install rsplib-tools` - also see https://www.uni-due.de/~be0001/rserpool/index.html

Answer (score 6):

The name of the default Terminal application in Ubuntu is `gnome-terminal`. That is why entering `terminal` doesn't open it.

To open it, enter the following -

```
gnome-terminal
```

Comment: An upvote then, you beat me to the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's not Windows. It's Ubuntu. You cannot open another terminal within the terminal with your command. Most of the commands are really different than what we expect in Ubuntu. The command is not the same as program name. You should type `gnome-terminal` to open another terminal's instance within a terminal.

Comment: I'm using Kubuntu 14.04 and I can open Konsole <2> from Konsole by typing command `konsole`